# jQuery: select element from array

Tags: jquery, arrays, select, element

I'm working with this function, but it doesn't work correctly: only the last element works.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```js
function hover_action() {

    var array = ["elem1","elem2","elem3","elem4"];

    $(array).each(function( index, value ) { 
        value1 = "#box-" + value + " img";
        value2 = "div#name-" + value;
        $(value1).hover(function(){
            $(value2).fadeIn(300);
        }, function(){
            $(value2).fadeOut(300);
        });
    });
}
```

Her is my HTML code:

```html
<div>
    <div id="box-elem1"><img src="path1" /></div>
    <div id="name-elem1"><span>NAME 1</span><div>
</div>
<div>
    <div id="box-elem2"><img src="path2" /></div>
    <div id="name-elem2"><span>NAME 2</span><div>
</div>
<div>
    <div id="box-elem3"><img src="path3" /></div>
    <div id="name-elem3"><span>NAME 3</span><div>
</div>
.
.
.
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: not a good idea to bind event in a loop which is called in a function.

Comment: There is no way for us to asses why it's not working without some relevant html

Comment: You are defining `value2` (and `value1` btw but doesn't really matter here) as global, that's why. Use `var` statement: `var value2 = "div#name-" + value;`

Answer (score 2):

Try something similar:

```
$('div[id^="box-"]').hover(function(){
            $(this).next('div[id^="name-"]').fadeIn(300);//asuming the next element is the element you want to hover
        }, function(){
            $(this).next('div[id^="name-"]').fadeOut(300);
        });
```

And for god's sake use classes

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d38far3z/)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you this:

```js
var $els = $("#elem1, #elem2, #elem3, #elem4");

$els.hover(function() {
  $("div#name-" + this.id).fadeIn(300);
}, function() {
  $("div#name-" + this.id).fadeOut(300);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the correct solution was by Izumi, but his/her answer has disappeared from this thread (?)

```
function hover_action() {

    var array = ["elem1","elem2","elem3","elem4"];

    $.each(array,function( index, value ) { 
        value1 = "#box-" + value + " img";
        value2 = "div#name-" + value;
        $(value1).hover(function(){
            $(value2).fadeIn(300);
        }, function(){
            $(value2).fadeOut(300);
        });
    });
}
```

thanks to Izumi...

The reason why OP code is not working is because of wrong use of selector. In JQuery, `$()` is element selector which aim at DOM object. `array` is javascript variable so it is not working. `$.each` is the correct way to iterate through javascript variable.

[Reference from JQuery: jQuery.each()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)